# Passing parameters from JSP page to servlet without using form parameters

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have been trying to pass parameters from my welcome.jsp page to details.java servlet.But the value that I am getting in servlet details.java is null.
Here's the code for welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<% 
String n=(String)session.getAttribute("name");
if(n==null)response.sendRedirect("login.html");

%>
Hello there!!
<%
out.println(n+"<br>");
String u=(String)session.getAttribute("userid");
out.println(u);
HttpSession session1=request.getSession();  
session1.setAttribute("userid",u); 
%>


<h3>Click here to see your salary details</h3>
<form action="Details">

<button>Salary details</button>
</form>
<h3>Click here to see your other details</h3>
<form action="">
<button>Other</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code for servlet details.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println(request.getParameter("userid"));
    //out.println(userid+"<br>");
    
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}
```

The output that I'm getting is

```
null Served at: /login
```

Is there any way in which I can pass these parameter values to my servlet without using form?

Comment: `request.getParameter("userid")` - you set the attribute on the `session`, not on the request.

Comment: That worked...thankyou!!

Answer (score -1):

you should use the **c:set** element from the core library and set scope to request. Example from the docs:

```
<c:set var="foo" scope="request" value="..."/>
```

Don't forget to declare the tag library at the top of your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```